# Why can't Clang find my header files while GCC can?

Tags: c, clang, static-libraries

I have a static library (`libdstruct.a`) that I need to link to my code. I have the library in some "lib" folder inside some "src" folder.

I tried all possible ways with Clang and got all sorts of errors, for example:

```
clang12 --std=c11 -g3 *.c lib/libdstruct.a -o bin/executable -I /usr/include/openssl -lcrypto
secret.c:5:10: fatal error: 'ds_list.h' file not found
#include <ds_list.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

GCC surprisingly worked fine:

`gcc10 --std=c11 -g3 *.c lib/libdstruct.a -o bin/executable -I /usr/include/openssl -lcrypto`

Any clue? I'm running this on FreeBSD 13, using Clang version 12.

Comment: That's not a linking error you quoted, that's a *compiler* error that hasn't got anything to do with linking or whether linking will (later) succeed or fail. Probably best to use that bit of information troubleshooting this. Clang can't locate the header file "ds_list.h", presumably in the include path(s). You need to find out what your include path(s) are for the invocation of Clang and make sure there is "ds_list.h" in one of these -- I assume likely in `/usr/include/openssl` -- or amend the paths to include the folder where you expect the file to be.

Comment: Thanks @amn, but how come gcc doesn't need the header files be presented?

Comment: @Rand0m They both need the header files included by your source code, but they may be looking in different places for them.  Where does `ds_list.h` live?  Try to figure out why `gcc` can find it but `clang` cannot.  What is your include path for `clang` vs. `gcc`?  Use `-I` to add missing path components.

Comment: added 
clang12 --std=c11 -g3 *.c lib/libdstruct.a -o bin/executable -I /usr/include/openssl -lcrypto -I /usr/local/include/
and it worked...
thanks so much @TomKarzes

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, I got it working by adding -I /path to the header files.
Thanks again and I really appreciate your help.